# Same answers when a new question just appears

Tags: discussion, answers, new-users

New question appears and you give the first answer.

Some seconds or minutes later another member gives the same or approximately the same answer.

This second answer goes automatically above the first one.

And, many time, that this second answer who receive votes.

For a newcomer like me it's pretty discouraging.

Comment: `This second answer goes automatically above the first one.` No, it doesn't. Do you have some repeatable evidence?

Comment: Today it look like this.

Comment: Repeatable evidence is not a single comment without a link.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi for examples this Q: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946104/adding-a-search-bar-into-main-menu-on-bootstrap/) or this one [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936374/i-need-to-put-back-change-wordpress-address-url-should-be-simple/)

Comment: Okay, so your first link has an upvoted accepted answer from an answerer different from the questioner, so that settles it. The second one has (currently) three zero-voted answers, so they will go round-robin about which one is taking first place as time passes.

Comment: For the first link and before the upvoted answer, mine was at the bottom. For the second, what do you mean by "as time passes", seconds, hours, days? Thanks for the explanation. Perhaps it's only a noob problem and have to experiment more and more without thinking of reputation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If two answers have the same **votes** then they are randomly ordered, this was done just to give all a chance and to limit the effect of the [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

If you refresh that question, you'll see the order flip around.

Comment: Come on, `reputation` does not apply to posts, so what will you use here? Points? Score? Votes? Tally? Inquiring minds want to know :)

Comment: Thanks. So if a member have a higher reputation, his answer not goes first?

Comment: @Jérôme, nope. Answers with the same vote tally are randomly sorted among themselves.

Comment: correct. Answers are sorted with the accepted one first, then the rest by score, answers with the same score in random order. Post time, author rep (and anything else you think might matter like length, number of comments etc) are ignored on the Votes view, which is the default.

Comment: @Kate, unless the answerer is the same user as the questioner, in which case his answer will not benefit from the "priority to accepted" sort order.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Nice to hear, was a bit afraid about the idea of reputation ordering answers.

Comment: I would say 'reputation' should be 'votes' to clarify this answer, but I've been noticing lately that (even on old questions) it's been totally random (which I think is rather annoying). Is it just me or was there another change with the ordering?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, you were welcome to edit that error out, but I took care of it.

Comment: I don't know if that's true any more on SO, I'm seeing even deleted answers mixed in randomly with the others, and score doesn't seem to be a factor.

Comment: @WesleyMurch, well maybe a mod or someone from the team could chime in and let us know the new paradigm.

Comment: On closer inspection, it appears to be ordering by time posted now. Something definitely seems different. I didn't see anything in the "change log": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange However, I think the OP is talking about the order when you "Show new answers" which may be different.

Comment: @WesleyMurch you might have switched to Oldest or Active by mistake

Comment: @KateGregory Yep you're right - I didn't notice and don't remember ever touching it (pretty much just noticed that feature after your comment). What is the "default"? "Active"?

Comment: I believe it is Votes. All the discussion here has been describing the behaviour of Votes

Comment: @WesleyMurch It remembers what tab you were on last, so if you (accidentally) clicked on he "oldest" tab, henceforth you will get the answers shown sorted by time, until you switch tabs again.